# Finding a composite expansion by using singular perturbation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am trying to find a composite expansion by singular perturbation method of the following problem
$$\epsilon y''+\sqrt{x}y'+y=0,  y(0)=0,y(1)=\frac{1}{e^2}$$

for outer solution I got $$y\sim e^{-2\sqrt{x}}+....$$ 
I can show the work if anyone needs to see it. I believe I am right about the solution.
Now for the Inner solution we need scaling and I have used $\bar{x}=\frac{x}{\epsilon^\gamma}$ near x=0. By balancing the dominant terms I got $\gamma=\frac{2}{3}$. Hence my scaling becomes $\bar{x}=\frac{x}{\epsilon^\frac{2}{3}}$. Using that my equation now becomes $$Y''+\sqrt{\bar{x}}Y'+\epsilon^{\frac{1}{3}}Y=0$$ Now I am a little bit confused. Should I take the expansion as $$Y\sim Y_0+\epsilon Y_1+.....$$ or $$Y\sim Y_0+\epsilon^\frac{2}{3} Y_1+.....$$ One more question is that do I need to use scaling also for x=1 like $\bar{x}=\frac{x-1}{\epsilon^\gamma}$.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed $y_{outer}=C·e^{-2\sqrt x}$.

By exploring the possible equations for inner solutions, one finds that their left limit always diverges to infinity. Thus the only point to center an inner solution at is at $x=0$. And indeed the reduced differential equation for $Y(X)=y(ϵ^{2/3}X)$ is
$$
Y''(X)+\sqrt{X}Y'=0
$$
with solution
$$
Y(X)=C+D·\int_0^Xe^{-\frac23s^{3/2}}\,ds
$$

---

The outer solution satisfying the right boundary  condition is $y_{outer}(x)=e^{-2\sqrt x}$. $y_{outer}(0)=1$ requires that $Y(0)=0$ and $Y(\infty)=1$, thus $C=0$ and $D=\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac23s^{3/2}}\,ds\right)^{-1}$. Then $y_{inner}(x)=Y(x/ϵ^{2/3})$ and the approximation is as usual
$$
y_{approx}(x)=y_{outer}(x)-y_{outer}(0)+y_{inner}
$$